# Is Application Insight's TelemetryClient Thread Safe?

Tags: c#, multithreading, azure, azure-application-insights

On this link: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-insights-api-custom-events-metrics/

It explicitly says:

> TelemetryClient is thread-safe.
>
> We recommend you use an instance of TelemetryClient for each module of your app.

However, the MSDN documentation (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/microsoft.applicationinsights.telemetryclient.aspx) says:

> Any public static (Shared in Visual Basic) members of this type are thread safe. Any instance members are not guaranteed to be thread safe.

So the problem is, most functions such as TrackEvent and TrackMetric are not static. If I follow the first article, having a singleton instance for my web service, would I run into threading problems?

Comment: You will not run into threading problems. If you need me to I can go into further detail i can, but for all intensive purposes you will not run into threading problems.

Comment: The [new docs page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.applicationinsights.telemetryclient) that the MSDN link in the question redirects to does not have the contradictory not-thread-safe disclaimer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The MSDN Docs are frequently incorrect when they say a given class is not thread-safe. I'm not sure how people have to flag their code to get those docs to reflect a class's thread-safety, but I've seen numerous instances where those docs are incorrect.

The current version of [the Azure article you linked](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-insights-api-custom-events-metrics/) says:

> TelemetryClient is thread-safe.
>
> For ASP.NET and Java projects, incoming HTTP Requests are automatically captured. You might want to create additional instances of TelemetryClient for other module of your app. For instance, you may have one TelemetryClient instance in your middleware class to report business logic events. You can set properties such as UserId and DeviceId to identify the machine. This information is attached to all events that the instance sends.
>
> ```
> TelemetryClient.Context.User.Id = "...";
> TelemetryClient.Context.Device.Id = "...";
> ```

That last bit is extremely important. Even though the class is thread-safe, if you are writing something like a web application where the UserId might change, you should probably reuse an instance of the telemetry client for each scope in which these values would all be the same (like each Request), but not as a static/singleton instance.

#### Update

In ASP.NET Core, Application Insights makes heavy use of dependency injection and registers TelemetryClient as a singleton! As explained in [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/asp-net-core#how-can-i-track-telemetry-thats-not-automatically-collected):

> We don't recommend creating new `TelemetryClient` instances in an ASP.NET Core application. A singleton instance of `TelemetryClient` is already registered in the `DependencyInjection` container, which shares `TelemetryConfiguration` with rest of the telemetry. Creating a new `TelemetryClient` instance is recommended only if it needs a configuration that's separate from the rest of the telemetry.

This means you should *avoid* setting variables on the client context which you don't want to be used throughout the application, and instead leverage Telemetry Initializers to set things like the user ID on each telemetry object.

Comment: Can you add a citation for the ASP.NET Core singleton registration pls?

Comment: @gabe: Yup. Done.

Answer (score 10):

TelemetryClient is thread safe.  A valid usage is to create a singleton and reuse it.  You will not run into issues reusing an instance.

Comment: you might want to use new instances of TelemetryClient from various places though, so that you can set an operation id or other fields that you might want to use to link telemetry together.  for example, request+dependency, or pageview+dependency use a shared operation id so that you can find dependency calls that came from a specific request or pageview.  if you just use one telemetryclient in the whole of your app, it's a little harder to do that.

Comment: Each TelemtryClient will create its own channel, its own copies of telemetry initializers, processors etc. It is a waste of resources. Managing fields should be done though telemetry initializer and common container like HttpContext or OperationContext or some DI.

Comment: Is there documentation that mentions it or the suggested ways to use it? The [official doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.applicationinsights.telemetryclient?view=azure-dotnet) doesn't have any recommendation. Looking at other sources, it sounds that it can be useful to have [multiple instances](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/fefbea33-2f0c-4cb0-9864-25cf9f1991d2/is-telemetryclient-threadsafe?forum=ApplicationInsights) of TelemetryClient and this usage would depend on the scenario.